# syntax in JSON array

Tags: php, json

In order to output it in the grid, i must have a JSON syntax like the one below:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "SupplierID": 1,
        "CompanyName": "Exotic Liquids",
        "ContactName": "Charlotte Cooper",
        "ContactTitle": "Purchasing Manager",
        "Address": "49 Gilbert St.",
        "City": "London",
        "Region": null,
        "PostalCode": "EC1 4SD",
        "Country": "UK",
        "Phone": "(171) 555-2222",
        "Fax": null,
        "HomePage": null
    },
    {
        "SupplierID": 2,
        "CompanyName": "New Orleans Cajun Delights",
        "ContactName": "Shelley Burke",
        "ContactTitle": "Order Administrator",
        "Address": "P.O. Box 78934",
        "City": "New Orleans",
        "Region": "LA",
        "PostalCode": "70117",
        "Country": "USA",
        "Phone": "(100) 555-4822",
        "Fax": null,
        "HomePage": "#CAJUN.HTM#"
    },....more data...
        ]
}
```

This is the code i am using:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('testdb')or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("select * from city");
$data[]=array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 $jsondata=json_encode($rows);
 echo $data[$jsondata];
}
```

But i am having certain errors. 
`Notice: Undefined index:`

How Can i fix this?, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding data too early. Normally you should construct entire multidimensional array and only then go about encoding it

```
mysql_select_db('testdb') or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("select * from city");

$data = array('data' => array());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data['data'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the encoded data to the array first

```
$data =array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 $jsondata=json_encode($rows);
 $data[] = $jsondata;
}
```

now you can echo the whole thing (there might be an easier way)

```
echo explode( $data, ',' );
```

also, i think you might be able to encode the whole array at once.